# Convert Regression output to classification based on prospective performance of model

Tags: regression, uncertainty, logistic

Let’s say I have a regression model that predicts experimental value in the range of 4 to 8 of an object based on a set of features. I am aiming to design an oBject with an experimental value of great than 7. When looking at how well the model performs prospectively in regards to predicting experimental results I see that only 50% of objects with predicted values above 7 have experimental values above 7. There are factors impacting the  I want to capture this probability based on prospective performance in a second model.

If I create a logistic regression model using the previous model’s predictions as features and the experimental values being above 7 as a target (0 for below 7 and 1 for above 7), I get a reasonable approximation for the probability that the prediction will